# Accessing value from defn

Tags: clojure

I need advice,
I try to make function :

```
(def user-map [new-name new-phone new-email]
  {:name new-name
   :phone new-phone
   :email new-email})
```

With new-name, new-phone, new-email are user input. But when i try to compile it, it says too many arguments to def, after change def to defn, when i try to execute user-map in REPL i get something like

> `#<temp_atom$user_address zenedu.mm.dbase.temp_atom$user_address@714924b5`

instead of actual map.

I need to get to the map, any advice?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like perhaps you are conceptually combining the value that will be returned from calling user-map as a function with some arguments and evaluating the symbol user-map on its own.

Evaluating

```
(user-map "me" "123456789" "me@here.com")
```

Which will return a map, by looking up the var user-map in the current namespace and calling the function stored in that var with these arguments. Where evaluating just

```
user-map
```

Will simply look up the var user-map in the current namespace and return the contents of that var, which in the case where you used defn, will be the function it's self. The REPL then prints the object I'd of that function.

Answer (score 0):

In your use case, you need `defn` to define a builder (like a constructor in Java) for the object you want. The log

```
#<temp_atom$user_address zenedu.mm.dbase.temp_atom$user_address@714924b5
```

suggests that you are using another structure `user-address` somewhere in the application and it looks like there is confusion between a `user-map` object and this `user-address`.

Anyway, you may be interested to have a look at `defrecord` that provides a convenient way to build objects with a constructor (and potentially other functions related to this object), e.g.

```
(defrecord user [name phone email])
```

`defrecord` provides 2 constructors `->user` and `map->user`:

```
(def me  (->user "abb" "0102030405" "abb@mail.com"))
(def you  (map->user {:email "das@mail.com" :phone "9090909090" :name "das"}))
```

And you can access the properties of a user through keywords exactly like a map:

```
user> (:name me)
"abb"
user> (:phone you)
"9090909090"
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, you should use `defn` instead of `def`.

But what information really varies here? The number and order of the map keys, in this case `[:name :phone :email]`.

A generic function that will build - from a *key* sequence - a *function* that will build the map from the *value* sequence is

```
(defn map-builder [keys]
  (fn [& values] (zipmap keys values)))
```

You can then define

```
(def user-map (map-builder [:name :phone :email]))
```

... which works as required:

```
(user-map "me" "123456789" "me@here.com")
;{:email "me@here.com", :phone "123456789", :name "me"}
```

If performance is pressing, by all means use records instead of maps, as [@AbbéRésina suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28781164/1562315).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use def in this instance:

```
(def user-map-other
  (fn [new-name new-phone new-email]
    {:name new-name
     :phone new-phone
     :email new-email}))
```

To gain access to the values contained in your function we can use `get` in this instance.

```
(get (user-map-other "Ben" "999" "bbb@mail.com") :phone) => "999"
(get (user-map-other "Ben" "999" "bbb@mail.com") :name) => "Ben"
(get (user-map-other "Ben" "999" "bbb@mail.com") :email) => "bbb@mail.com"
```

A more concise method would be to use `defn` as represented below.

```
(defn user-map [new-name new-phone new-email]
  {:name new-name
   :phone new-phone
   :email new-email})

(get (user-map "Ben" "999" "bbb@mail.com") :phone) => "999"
(get (user-map "Ben" "999" "bbb@mail.com") :name) => "Ben"
(get (user-map "Ben" "999" "bbb@mail.com") :email) => "bbb@mail.com"
```